# Implementing Barcode Scanner in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, barcode-scanner

I'm planning to create a web application for a set of pharmacy stores. I'm using Laravel and MySQL. The problem is that I've never used Barcode Scanner, so I do not know how it is operated. And my question is "How can I use Barcode Scanner and implement it in my Laravel application?"

Comment: Read and try [milon barcode](https://github.com/milon/barcode)

Comment: try this http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-barcode-generator-example-using-milon-barcode-packageexample.html

Comment: Thanks, now I have some understanding about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A barcode is a representation of numbers or characters.

The scanner will read the barcode and output it as a string.

I would recommand you trying the scanner your own open a notepad, and scan a code you will understand the behavior. It's the same as writing yourself on your keyboard but obviously faster and safer.

For your question the easiest way to do that is to force the focus on an input, then it will be filled when the user scan something.